# link function being called twice in directive

Tags: angularjs

In my HTML, I'm looping over an array of items, and calling a directive for each one:

```
<tr ng-repeat="oPublisherActivity in PublisherActivityCtrl.aPublisherActivity">
    <td>
        <publisher-activity-details activity-log="{{oPublisherActivity}}">
        </publisher-activity-details>
    </td>
</tr>
```

However, the directive is being called twice for each element.

This is because I'm calling $compile inside my link function. If I don't use the $compile function, the directive is called once as expected.

Is there a way I can get this so that the link function is only called once for each element?

Note also that on each second call the scope.activityLog is an empty string.

```
oPublisherActivityModule.directive('publisherActivityDetails', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            activityLog: '@',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            $compile(element.html(details(angular.fromJson(scope.activityLog))))(scope);
        }
   };
}]);
```

Comment: Are you updating PublisherActivityCtrl.aPublisherActivity array?

Comment: No, once we loop over the array, we don't care if its changed

Comment: Of course it will be called twice. When you compile the html of the directive you are actually recompiling the entire directive. So: (1) Why do you want to compile? Usually there is another way. (2) If you really need to compile, try compiling the contents of the element, instead of the entire element. (3) I guess the code above is incomplete, or you are not doing anything with the output of the compilation. And there are no contents of the element of the directive, so as it is, the compilation is not needed.

Comment: I'm compiling because the details() function (not shown) generates sx-sref tags, which need to be compiled to href tags

Comment: Thanks Nikos, your point number (2) fixed it. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it